# Google cloud endpoint .api file being deleted from the war when switching to objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-endpoints, google-plugin-eclipse

Having created a successfully (locally) deployed service using Google cloud endpoints I wanted to switch from using JDO to Objectify instead.

Having update the endpoint class with the objectify code I have an issue where the .api file in the war is deleted and doesn't get regenerated.  The upshot is that the endpoint is no longer exposed and every request returns a 404 error.

I manually added the file back in (amended from another project) and it worked once with the war deployed and it appearing to try and serve the request (failed due to missing objectify annotation) but then deleted the .api file again.

Can anyone help me with any suggestions as to what may be causing the file to be deleted and not re-generated at all?

Comment: Try looking for an error in the Eclipse logs. Does that show anything? It's possible there is an error in generating your API, thus deleting the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Holevoet's comment helped to solve this one.

It turns out that there is a problem with the parameterized objectivity key which was shown in the stack trace.  Removing the Key fields caused the .api files to be re-generated successfully.

As pointed out in the comment below - this is expected to be resolved in the next version of the SDK.

Comment: Objectify Key types are unsupported in the currently-released SDK. They'll be supported in the next release.